# extract summary from matrix lm object

Tags: r, matrix, statistics, linear-regression, lm

I'd like to get the coefficients from the summary section of an lm object, except I inputted a matrix and I am getting null for the summary part. Here is my code:

```
n=12
y=rnorm(n,23,1)
x1=rnorm(n,23,1)
x2=rnorm(n,15.5,1)
lm1=lm(y~x1+x2)
n2=10
b0=4;b1=2;b2=3
sim1<-function(){
  randmat=matrix(rnorm(n*n2,0,8),n,n2)
  x1mat=matrix(x1,n,n2)
  x2mat=matrix(x2,n,n2)
  return(b0+b1*x1mat+b2*x2mat+randmat)
}
sim1=sim1()
lm1=lm(sim1~x1+x2)
c2=summary(lm1)$coefficients

> c2
NULL
```

what I want is this (but repeated):

```
lm2=lm(sim1[,1]~x1+x2)
summary(lm2)$coefficients
```

Does anyone know how to extract these? Thanks

-Rik

Comment: Try `do.call("c",apply(sim1, 2, function(x) list(summary(lm(x~x1+x2))$coefficients))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way is to do the following after the end of the following line of your code.

```
lm1=lm(sim1~x1+x2) #this runs 10 models
```

All the coefficients will be stored in the list `summary(lm1)` as `Response Y1` ... to `Response Y10` (i.e. 10 models as many as `ncol(sim1)`).

In order to get the coefficients from each model back you could do:

```
all_coef <- lapply( paste0('Response Y', 1:ncol(sim1)),  
                    function(x) summary(lm1)[[x]]$coefficients)
```

Or as @Rik mentions in the comment it will be faster if `summary(lm1)` is not repeated in the lapply loop in case you have a big matrix.

```
the_sum  <- summary(lm1)
all_coef <- lapply( paste0('Response Y', 1:ncol(sim1)),  
                    function(x) the_sum[[x]]$coefficients)
```

And the output would be:

```
> all_coef
[[1]]
              Estimate Std. Error   t value  Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 135.242552  80.136427  1.687654 0.1257496
x1           -4.777486   2.953534 -1.617549 0.1402142
x2            4.464435   3.891641  1.147186 0.2808857

[[2]]
               Estimate Std. Error     t value  Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 119.1772823 111.603046  1.06786765 0.3133851
x1           -0.1376013   4.113277 -0.03345297 0.9740435
x2           -1.2946027   5.419744 -0.23886785 0.8165585

[[3]]
              Estimate Std. Error    t value  Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) -51.329923  63.495202 -0.8084063 0.4397018
x1            3.721227   2.340199  1.5901325 0.1462682
x2            3.793981   3.083498  1.2304147 0.2497304

[[4]]
               Estimate Std. Error     t value   Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 124.8606014  57.669842  2.16509352 0.05857967
x1           -1.2517705   2.125498 -0.58893044 0.57039201
x2           -0.1159803   2.800603 -0.04141263 0.96787111

#...and so on until 10
```

To get the individual coefficients for a model just do:

```
all_coef[[<the_number_you_want>]]
```

Comment: I see, I was indexing over summary(lm1[[x]])$coefficients. Not sure why I couldn't figure that out... Thanks

Comment: @Rik Np, sometimes we all need a bit of help even for things we know (including myself). Glad I could be of help :)

Comment: The code runs slow for large n, it's better to take summary(lm1) outside the lapply...

Comment: @Rik Oh yeah certainly. I didn't know how big your matrix was but yeah definitely running summary(lm1) outside the lapply will be much faster.